# Passthrough not working in Oculus Quest 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, oculusquest

**GOAL**

I imported Meta XR Integration package and Meta XR Simulator. Project platform is Android.

I recorded video but passthrough is black screen in the video.

Why is the black screen in the video?

**CONTENT**

I use Built-in and Unity2022.3.8f1. I am using Meta XR Integration 57.0.

I tried for enable passthrough from some community and forum but it is not working.

[OVR Camera Rig Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VezZK.png)

[Passthrough Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID5Nn.png)

[CenterEyeAnchor Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEJfu.png)

What should I do for fix this issue?

Please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This passthrough setting is correct.

Unfortunately, you can't do this natively on the Quest 2 as Meta blocks you from doing so for privacy reasons. If you do try to record passthrough, using Meta's built in recorder, you just get an empty black screen where you room would be. Interestingly enough, this is not an issue for Meta Quest Pro users.